# Saving an integer into an array of strings using sprintf()

Tags: c, integer, argv

I'm having trouble storing an integer into an array of strings using sprintf().  I am trying to  create a new argv list to pass into my child process.  I have 'curr' storing the correct value since I've tested in in GDB.  My code is as follows:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h> /* for pid_t */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

static char *argv2[] = {"./datagen", "10", "outputfile", "SIGUSR1"};

pid_t pid = fork();
int curr = getpid();
sprintf(argv2[4], "%s", curr);


if(pid == 0)
{
    printf("You are in the child process.\n");

}
else{
    printf("You are in the parent process.  Process ID is %d\n", getpid());
}


return;
}
```

After exhaustively searching around for a clear answer, I have yet to find anything.  Ideally, the 4th slot of argv2 will store the process id as a string.  However, I am getting a segmentation fault 11.  If anyone could shed some light on this issue I would be eternally grateful.

Thank you!!

Comment: `char buf[sizeof curr * CHAR_BIT/3 + 3]; sprintf(buf, "%d", curr);`

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that

```
static char *argv2[] = {"./datagen", "10", "outputfile", "SIGUSR1"};
```

is a declaration of an array of `char` pointers, which are pointing to string literals, and further more to four string literals only, you can't extend it nor modifiy the strings.

What you need is

```
char argv2[10][100] = {"./datagen", "10", "outputfile", "SIGUSR1"};
```

assuming that you want `10` strings of maximum length `100`, which you can obviously change.

Also, the format specifier for integers is `"%d"` so you have another mistake, having said all that you can now

```
sprintf(argv2[4], "%d", curr);
```

and I would suggest the `snprintf()` function, since it will avoid buffer overflow problems,

```
snprintf(argv2[4], sizeof(argv[4]), "%d", curr);
```

**chux** comment is correct if you want to have control on whether the specified length of the string was enough, you should check the return value of `snprintf()`, in case there wasn't sufficient space to write all the source string into the destination it will be truncated, if `snprintf()` returns a value larger or equal to the requested maximum, it means that the string was truncated, so a simple check like

```
if (snprintf(argv2[4], sizeof(argv[4]), "%d", curr) >= sizeof(argv[4]))
    doSomething_TheString_Was_Truncated();
```

although, for `100` characters and the `"%d"` that will not happen, but I firmly believe that people must write safe code as a habit, rather than only checking possible problems, check for every thing that can conceptually go wrong, no matter how unlikely. Because sometimes there will be situations where an unexpected thing will happen.

**Note**: as **chux** pointed out again, `snprintf()` will return a negative in case of an error, you can check for that separately, to check if there was an error.

Comment: Using `snprintf()` vs. `sprintf()` does prevent buffer overflow problems but trades an overflow problem with another.  Unless the return value of `snprintf()` is checked, the truncated result in `argv2[4]` is indistinguishable from valid results.  Thus later code will operate with an invalid value in the string.  IMO, an unchecked  `snprinf()` provides a false sense of protection.  Recommend showing how to check the result.

Comment: Nice improvement.. Pedantic point: `snprintf()` return value could be negative "if an encoding error occurred."

Answer (score 1):

Simple steps:
***1)*** Determine array size information from existing `argv`, `argc` arguments.

```
int i, len=0, lenKeep=21;//initialize large enough to contain pid integer
for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
{
    len = strlen(argv[i])
    if(lenKeep<len)lenKeep = len;
}
```

***2)*** use that size information to create a new string array, `argv2`, with additional elements if necessary. (argv2 will be an array of strings, create sufficient space.)

```
char argv2[argc+1][lenKeep+1];    
//argc+1 allows for additional array element
//lenKeep+1 provides space for all existing content
```

***3)*** add new information to the string array in the normal way.

```
sprintf(argv2[argc], "%d", curr); //argv2 array contains argc + 1 elements 
                                  //so now argc is a valid index value
```

Comment: @chux - Yeah, you beat me to the punch by a few seconds.  Good catch. Thanks

Comment: Suggest `lenKeep = MAX_INT_LENGTH` like `lenKeep = 21`, for it is not known the `strlen(argv[i])` is big enough for the string version of `curr`.

Comment: I don't know, but I find this style `if(lenKeep<len)lenKeep = len;` really confusing, any reason you could give for using that? I would like to learn if there is a good reason, since I see it very often.

Comment: It makes sense, but it's ugly.

Comment: @iharob - Lol!.  If this syntax is ugly to you, I suspect you will avoid using it . :)

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf(argv2[4], "%s", curr);` breaks the array, which has only 4 elements.

Even if it has more elements, you are writing to a string literal which is Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try using %d instead of %s, it should anyways be saved as a C string.